# Noun adjuncts, possessive or using "of"

Tags: synonyms, attributive-nouns, possessive-s-vs-of

*meta:* This is my first time on your site. I have been teaching English for longer than I care to mention (native speaker).

I am trying to find a way of explaining to some intermediate students why we can say, for example, "**the Channel Tunnel entrance**" (in Folkestone) but we cannot say "**the Eiffel Tower top**".

I have seen some discussions on use of noun adjuncts/possessive but not on this example using *of*.

Comment: You could technically use 'the Eiffel Tower upper floors'. No-one would literally be on 'the Eiffel Tower top' :)

Comment: Why can't we say "the Eiffel Tower top"? Isn't it just another way to say "the top of the eiffel Tower"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I certainly would be inclined to say we went to the top of the Eiffel Tower but never say Eiffel Tower top. It's usage, but I don't know the rule (if there is one ;-)

Comment: The general tendency -- and it's no more than a tendency -- is for the Germanic _-'s_ possessive to be used for persons (or living beings) possessing, while the Romance _of_ possessive is used for non-living things. Even (perhaps especially) metaphorically: e.g, _Bill's foot ~ ??the foot of Bill, the dog's nose ~ ?the nose of the dog, ??the table's head/leg/foot ~ the head/leg/foot of the table_.

Comment: I don't see much that is discordant about 'The Eiffel-Tower summit'. But I tend to agree that some of these expressions sound right, others don't; and I suppose it is a question of custom. For example I might say the 'Everest summit', but 'the summit of Mount Everest'. With the full formal name it seems more essential to use the 'of' form.

Comment: The usage of *the ---- top* seems quite restricted, and interestingly when there is a 'top' e.g. the mountain top, desk top, table top, roof top, tree top, stove top, hill top, the compound form seems nearly always more popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm intuiting that it's to do with compositionality - that is, the *Channel Tunnel entrance* is a component of the Channel Tunnel, but the top of the Eiffel Tower isn't a part of the Tower - it's a location on it. Just as you can't say *the Channel Tunnel middle/end/beginning*. *Channel Tunnel start* is questionable.

I think the explanation would be:

- If the entity is a component of the whole (***Eiffel tower*** base/stairs/lifts) then you can use it as a qualifier, otherwise;
- You need to use it as a focus (*the bottom/top/middle/outside **of** the Eiffel Tower*)

Comment: Thank you for your input, sounds pretty good to me. This is really a difficult area for learners of English as I have never found a hard and fast rule. I have just looked up compositionality which is apparently a hotly debated subject, thank you for your insights.

Comment: @jennifer Agreed, in fact, as native speakers, often concepts that we can intuit are difficult to verbalise. Although you and I can look at any given utterance and "feel" whether it is grammatical, this unconscious mastery means that we can necessarily teach it to others.

Comment: @jimsugDid you mean to say "doesn't mean" rather than "mean"? I hope so;-) otherwise I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: @jennifer absolutely.

Comment: I am not shouting from the roof tops but this argument holds little water.

Comment: @Kris, I am happy to upvote a more suitable answer :) Many concepts in English are still under much discussion and scrutiny, and this is based on my own, limited experience in, and knowledge of, the field.